# Custom MySQL docker image using existing sql file

Tags: mysql, docker, dockerfile, docker-machine

I want to create a custom MySQL docker image in https://labs.play-with-docker.com/ using existing mysql file. MySQL file looks like below.

abc.sql

```
create schema my-schema1;

use my-schema1;

create table table1(
id bigint primary key,
name varchar(50)
);
insert into table1 values(7009009001,'Carry');

select * from table1;

create schema my-schema2;

use my-schema2;

create table table2(
id bigint primary key,
name varchar(50)
);
insert into table1 values(4009009001,'Marry');

select * from table2;
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM mysql
COPY ./abc.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/abc.sql
```

I am running below commands :

```
docker pull mysql:latest 
docker build -f Dockerfile -t custom-mysql-img .
docker run --name=mysql-con  --volume custom-mysql-volume:/var/lib/mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root -d custom-mysql-img
docker exec -it mysql-con  mysql -u root -p
```

Container gets started and asks for password. But on executing `show databases;` command it only displays default schemas. I need multiple schemas and tables in my .sql file, hence don't want to put schema name in Dockerfile.
Please suggest where I am wrong.

Below is the output of `docker logs mysql-con` :

```
$ docker logs mysql-con
2021-04-18 13:16:39+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.23-1debian10 started.
2021-04-18 13:16:39+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
2021-04-18 13:16:40+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.23-1debian10 started.
2021-04-18 13:16:40+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Initializing database files
2021-04-18T13:16:40.236069Z 0 [System] [MY-013169] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.23) initializing of server in progress as process 42
2021-04-18T13:16:40.253242Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2021-04-18T13:16:40.923755Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2021-04-18T13:16:43.583388Z 6 [Warning] [MY-010453] [Server] root@localhost is created with an empty password ! Please consider switching off the --initialize-insecure option.
2021-04-18 13:16:47+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Database files initialized
2021-04-18 13:16:47+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Starting temporary server
2021-04-18T13:16:47.959622Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.23) starting as process 87
2021-04-18T13:16:48.100393Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2021-04-18T13:16:48.506573Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2021-04-18T13:16:48.753607Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
2021-04-18T13:16:49.015712Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2021-04-18T13:16:49.018919Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
2021-04-18T13:16:49.023237Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011810] [Server] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
2021-04-18T13:16:49.082436Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.23'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 0  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
2021-04-18 13:16:49+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Temporary server started.
Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/iso3166.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/leap-seconds.list' as time zone. Skipping it.
Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/zone.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/zone1970.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.

2021-04-18 13:16:55+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: running /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/abc.sql
/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: line 75: /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/abc.sql: Permission denied
2021-04-18 13:17:43+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.23-1debian10 started.
2021-04-18 13:17:43+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
2021-04-18 13:17:43+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.23-1debian10 started.
2021-04-18T13:17:44.067090Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.23) starting as process 1
2021-04-18T13:17:44.082414Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2021-04-18T13:17:45.999169Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2021-04-18T13:17:46.234843Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '::' port: 33060, socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
2021-04-18T13:17:46.322310Z 0 [System] [MY-010229] [Server] Starting XA crash recovery...
2021-04-18T13:17:46.378281Z 0 [System] [MY-010232] [Server] XA crash recovery finished.
2021-04-18T13:17:46.454642Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2021-04-18T13:17:46.455015Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
2021-04-18T13:17:46.459673Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011810] [Server] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
2021-04-18T13:17:46.491885Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.23'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
```

Comment: Is there anything interesting in `docker logs mysql-con` that suggests why the init scripts may or may not have run?  Does the named volume exist before you run the container (does `docker volume rm custom-mysql-volume` help)?

Comment: @DavidMaze added logs in question. Found below issue: 2021-04-18 13:16:55+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: running /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/abc.sql
/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: line 75: /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/abc.sql: Permission denied